# Protractor: how I can rightly use filtering in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, testing, filtering, protractor, cycle

I try to start testing with protractor and now I have a problem, that I can't solve.

I have this test:

```
 describe('Test_3', function() {
    var my_url = 'http://wks-15103:8010/ps/ng-components/examples/ps-checkbox.html'
    var main_checkbox = element(by.xpath("//div[@ng-model='My_Group']/div[1]/span/span[1]"));
    var checkbox_list = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@ng-model='My_Group']/div[2]/div/span/span[1]")); 
    var title_checkbox_list = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@ng-model='My_Group']/div[2]/div/span"));   
    var disabled_pri = 'n-check-checkbox';
    var enabled_pri = 'n-check-checkbox n-check-checkbox_checked';


    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get(my_url);
    });

    it('schould be chosen',function(){
        main_checkbox.click(); 

        checkbox_list.filter(function(elem, index) {
            return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(text) {
                return text != 'n-check-checkbox n-check-checkbox_disabled' & text!='n-check-checkbox n-check-checkbox_disabled n-check-checkbox_checked';
            });
        }).then(function(filteredElements) {
            filteredElements.each(function(element, index) {
                expect(element.getAttribute('class')).toEqual(disabled_pri); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It isn't working. 
But then I try to use filtering without cycle `.each` it is working fine.

```
 describe('Test_3', function() {
    var my_url = 'http://wks-15103:8010/ps/ng-components/examples/ps-checkbox.html'
    var main_checkbox = element(by.xpath("//div[@ng-model='My_Group']/div[1]/span/span[1]"));
    var checkbox_list = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@ng-model='My_Group']/div[2]/div/span/span[1]"));  //это список самих чекбоксов
    var title_checkbox_list = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@ng-model='My_Group']/div[2]/div/span"));  //это список чекбоксов с названиями  
    var disabled_pri = 'n-check-checkbox';
    var enabled_pri = 'n-check-checkbox n-check-checkbox_checked';

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get(my_url);
    });

    it('schould be chosen',function(){
        main_checkbox.click();     //Убрали флажок с группового чекбокса   

        checkbox_list.filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.getAttribute('class').then(function(text) {
            return text != 'n-check-checkbox n-check-checkbox_disabled' & text!='n-check-checkbox n-check-checkbox_disabled n-check-checkbox_checked';
        });
        }).then(function(filteredElements) {
            filteredElements[0].click();
            filteredElements[0].click();
            expect(filteredElements[0].getAttribute('class')).toEqual(disabled_pri);
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [docs for `filter`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) it returns an instance of [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder). When you call a `then` method on instance of `ElementArrayFinder`, it resolves to an array of [`ElementFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder)s, so in the callback for `then` you receive a pure JavaScript Array of `ElementFinder`s. To iterate it you can use native JavaScrupt [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
checkbox_list.filter(function(elem, index) {
    // ...
})
.then(function(filteredElements) {
    filteredElements.forEach(function(element, index) {
        // ....
    });
});
```

Otherwise, `ElementArrayFinder` has it's own method `each`, you should call it right on the result of `filter`, not inside a callback for `then`:

```
checkbox_list.filter(function(elem, index) {
    // ...
})
.each(function(element, index) {
    // ....
});
```

Maybe [the source code for `ElementArrayFinder`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2.1.0/lib/element.js) could also help you.

Comment: Hi, I have similar task to do but the thing is I want to check whether the class contains `disabled` as a `substring`. I want all the elements which do not have `disabled` as `substring` and then I want to click the 2 element in the collection. Can anyone please help me with the `filter` part.

Comment: @rahoolm, I think you should create a new question and describe you specific problem in there, providing examples of your actual code.